# Render shapefile with no projection in leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, shapefile, map-projections

I want to render a shapefile inside of a leaflet map.

[This shapefile](https://github.com/vgorte/shapefile) has no projection so I'm trying to give it one.

```
  directions <- readOGR("./directions/", "directions")
  proj4string(directions) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
```

And after that I try to add it to my map like this:

```
  map <- leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 

    addPolygons(data=directions,weight=1,col = 'black') %>% 

    setView(lng = -3.8196207,
            lat = 40.4678698,
            zoom = 10)
```

The problem is that I get an error saying:

> Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data:  450781.167295 4485221.863980

I tried using other projections as CRS like

```
  proj4string(directions) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs")
```

which does not give me an error but the shapefile is not getting rendered either.

I don't really understand why that happens and how I can fix it.

BTW: I got this shapefile from a spanish [website](http://datos.madrid.es/sites/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=33cb30c367e78410VgnVCM1000000b205a0aRCRD&vgnextchannel=374512b9ace9f310VgnVCM100000171f5a0aRCRD) where traffic and airquality data gets published

Comment: Maybe [Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441549/geographical-crs-given-to-non-conformant-data-in-r) is source of the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @user6617454 but my problem is that I don't get an error anymore and still cant see the shapefile on my map and I can't figure out why that is. I also looked at the coordinates `coordinates(direction)` and there seems to be no error. They seem to be as fine as one of my working shapefile that I rendered.

Comment: Seems like leaflet needs WGS 84 projection for display [leaflet for r](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. What you need to do is convert the projection from UTM Zone 17N to longitude and latitude projection.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

# Read the shapefile
directions <- readOGR("directions", "directions")
# Set the projection to be UTM zone 30N
proj4string(directions) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs")
# Conduct project transformation from UTM zone 30N to long-lat
directions_longlat <- spTransform(directions, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

map <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = directions_longlat, weight=1, col = 'black') %>% 
  setView(lng = -3.8196207,
          lat = 40.4678698,
          zoom = 10)
map
```

[image]